# MySQL stored procedure to INSERT DELAYED but CREATE TABLE first if needed?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, myisam

I'm planning on doing a lot of `INSERT DELAYED` into `MyISAM` tables.  But the tables might not exist yet.  Let's say e.g. a new table will exist for each day.

So instead of detecting absence of table in my client and creating then retrying the insert, it seems like a good case for a stored procedure ("function").

Is this possible, and what would it look like?
Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a waste of time to check with every single insert whether the table exist. If you *need* day by day tables (in my opinion they defy much of the logic usually found in databases, so I try to avoid them, I'd):

1. Create the default table to insert 'my_logging_table'.
2. Do all inserts / updates / deletes on that table.
3. Run a daily cronjob to create the table of yesterday ('my_logging_table-2010-06-15'), and inserting all of yesterdays records in it, after which they're deleted from the main table.
4. If that is to much of a rewrite for your application you could make an updatable view with the current tablename+day ('my_logging_table-2010-06-16'), which just inserts in the 'my_logging_table'

Another approach would be a MERGE table (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html), with a daily cronjob creating the 'today' table & updating the tablelist for the merge table with an alter table statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was actually suggesting that the INSERT go first, and then only handle table creation if the INSERT fails.  I agree checking for table on every INSERT is very wasteful!

Comment: The purpose for daily tables is to handle large volumes of constantly incoming data.  Your step#3 would be extremely data intensive and practically grind the system to a halt once a day.  This is basically what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If so, I'd go the MERGE table route & create a table once a day & add it to the merge table (possibly as the only table, MySQL won't mind).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be an idea to create a scheduled event that runs every night before midnight, and create the log-table for the next day. That way you could always rely on the table beeing created before any `INSERT` would occur?

```
CREATE EVENT createLogTable
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY  
STARTS '2010-6-20 23:59:00'   
DO
    BEGIN
        SET @tablename = CONCAT('my_logging_table-',DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)));
        SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`',@tablename,'` (`timestamp` INT,`event` VARCHAR( 20 )) ENGINE = MYISAM');
        PREPARE createStatement FROM @query;
        EXECUTE createStatement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE createStatement;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You may make a good scheme to accomplish the same.

For example, if you have a table "Logged_users", which will be created every day, you could just append a column to the users table, or make an extra table with *ID_USER, DAY* columns (that would be a better choice). Then, you may program a CRON job to delete every rows of past days, and execute that job every day at 12:00 am.